# parsing log file to get certain information

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, grep

I have a log file with following information. I need to parse it get some information. How do i use grep to get those information or any other method?

```
connection= 5,size=262144,put=10 get=0
swift-bench 2013-02-14 16:29:34,913 INFO Auth version: 1.0
swift-bench 2013-02-14 16:29:36,580 INFO Auth version: 1.0
swift-bench 2013-02-14 16:29:36,909 INFO 10 PUTS **FINAL** [0 failures], 30.6/s
swift-bench 2013-02-14 16:29:36,910 INFO Auth version: 1.0
swift-bench 2013-02-14 16:29:37,028 INFO 10 DEL **FINAL** [0 failures], 86.3/s
```

Desired output:

```
Connection,size,put,gets,operation,op/s
5,262144,10,0,PUTS,30.6
5,262144,10,0,DEL,86.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $nums;
while ( <> ) { 
    if ( $. == 1 ) { 
        my @fields = m/(\w+)=/g;
        push @fields, qw<operation op/s>;
        printf qq|%s\n|, join q|,|, @fields;

        $nums = join q|,|, m/=\s*(\d+)/g;

        next;
    }   

    my @f = split;
    if ( $f[5] !~ /(?i)version/ and @f > 7 ) { 
        printf qq|%s\n|, join q|,|, $nums, $f[5], substr( $f[ $#f ], 0, length( $f[ $#f ] ) - 2 );
    }   
}
```

And asumming `infile` with data posted in the question, run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

That yields:

```
connection,size,put,get,operation,op/s
5,262144,10,0,PUTS,30.6
5,262144,10,0,DEL,86.3
```

Comment: Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at parse_swift.pl line 17, <> line 2.
    ,PUTS,30.6
    ,DEL,86.3
It gives me the above output with error "use of unintialized value". I don't know much about perl, so can't figure out whats wrong. Thanks for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can count on the data being consistently formatted as shown, this will do it by playing tricks with IFS and chopping the lines up into the positional parameters. Assumes the log file's name is on the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

logfile=$1

echo "Connection,size,put,gets,operation,op/s"
tmpIFS="$IFS"  # In case we want to restore IFS later
IFS="$IFS,="
# Note that the read below isn't splitting up the line
# so the content of IFS isn't a problem
while read line ; do
    set -- $line
    case "$line" in
        connection*)
            conn="$2"  size="$4"   puts="$6"  gets="$8"
        ;;
        swift-bench*' PUTS '*|swift-bench*' DEL '*)
            shift 6
            case "$line" in
                *'**FINAL**'*) echo "$conn,$size,$puts,$gets,$1,$5" ;;
                *) echo "$conn,$size,$puts,$gets,$1,$4" ;;
            esac
        ;;
    esac

done < "$logfile"

IFS="$tmpIFS"  # Not needed if this is the end of the script
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works too but i have some lines like this   "swift-bench 2013-02-14 16:29:56,677 INFO 83 PUTS [0 failures], 39.8/s". Does it chop the line after each space? How do you count the position, after each space??

Comment: I've modified it to handle that format too - it's the same as the others but without **FINAL** so it's one "argument" shorter moving the time to $4 instead of $5. If you look at the way IFS is set, you can see it will break up the line on spaces (part of the original IFS value), commas and equal signs. That isn't necessary for the swift-bench lines, but it was for the connection line. (I didn't assume there was only one line beginning with "connection" so I wanted a consistent way of parsing all the lines.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
conn=`grep -P -o -e '\d+(?=,size)' logfile`
size=`grep -P -o -e '(?<=size\=)\d+' logfile`
put=`grep -P -o -e '(?<=put\=)\d+' logfile`
get=`grep -P -o -e '(?<=get\=)\d+' logfile`
for i in `grep -P -e 'INFO \d' logfile | awk '{print $6","$10}' | tr -d '/s'`; do
echo $conn,$size,$put,$get,$i
done
```